# cannot resolve symbol 'connect'

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

what is the problem here ? why i get always cannot resolve symbol 'connect'. i got this code from the documentation and my depencies are alle correct.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection("username", "password" ,"jabber.org");
conn1.connect();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: move this conn1.connect(); into a valid scope

Comment: you can not just pretend to do conn1.connect() out of a method....

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.  but i dont understand what you mean. what would be correct ?

Comment: Call it in onCreate

Comment: okay i did... i need a try catch for it. understandable. its a connection. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection("username", "password" ,"jabber.org");
conn1.connect();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

because `conn1.connect()` is not invoked in a valid scope...(should be done inside a method)
instead do

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection("username", "password" ,"jabber.org");

     public void connectToSomething()   ... some exceptions here must be thrown{

          conn1.connect();
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```